# Panning UIView after RotationGesture Causes view to collapse

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm going to try to describe with words something that might only be describable with video.

I have created a simple iOS app with a storyboard containing a single image view.  I have added two gesture recognizers: a UIPanGestureRecognizer and a UIRotationGestureRecognizer along with their corresponding IBActions.

When I first start the application in the simulator, the image view pans correctly.  The image view also rotates correctly.  After a rotation, however, any subsequent pan fails.  When I try to pan after a rotation, regardless of the direction of the pan, the image rapidly scales to zero and disappears, i.e., it collapses or implodes to a point that disappears.

The gesture recognizers are created using the following code.  myImageView is set up as an IBOutlet UIImageView.

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRec = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(processPan:)];
[myImageView addGestureRecognizer:panRec];
UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotRec = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(processRotation:)];
[myImageView addGestureRecognizer:rotRec];
```

I've written the associated actions as best I know how.  They are basically slight modifications of the methods I found in the iOS documentation.  These are shown below.

```
-(IBAction)processPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.view];
        CGRect newFrame = myImageView.frame;
        newFrame.origin.x += translation.x; 
        newFrame.origin.y += translation.y;
        myImageView.frame = newFrame;
        [sender setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
    }
}

-(IBAction)processRotation:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(myImageView.transform, sender.rotation);
        [sender setRotation:0];
    }
}
```

So what am I missing?    I am new at this, so hopefully my ignorance will be tolerated.

I am running Xcode version 4.2.1 on OS X version 10.7.3 on a MacBook if that helps.  Thank you so much for taking the time to read my question.  Stack Overflow is an unbelievable resource!

-Dave

Comment: Both gestures might be breaking because of rotation that is being done on the view they are watching. You could try adding a clear view on top of your UIImageView and attach the recognizers on the clear view.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if I've come up with a solution or if I've come up with a kludge.  Basically, the pan code wasn't working for me.  Any time the view was rotated or scaled, the panning code would seriously distort or collapse the view being translated.  I stared at transform matrices and frame coordinate systems until I just about went blind.

The translation code I listed in my first post was basically copied from Listing 3-2, "Handling pinch, pan, and double-tap gestures" from the Gesture Recognizers section out of Apple's Event Handling Guide for iOS, so I figured it would do the trick for me.  Well, I ended up writing my own code for it using the UIImageView center and not messing with the frame at all.  Here is what worked for me.

```
CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.superview];
CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(self.myImageView.center.x + translation.x, self.myImageView.center.y + translation.y);
[self.myImageView setCenter:newCenter];
[sender setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.superview];
```

I used the superview as a reference for the translation in case it was rotated.  It seems to work now.

This effort probably reveals something about how my understanding of frames isn't correct.  If someone can tell me how to correct my understanding, I'd appreciate it.

-Dave